# Converting span to input upon click

Tags: jquery

I have converting spans to input upon clicking and when click outside it becomes span again. But it just converts for once and then doesn't happen again

Here is the code.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'span.loadNum', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'unique',
                'value': $(this).html()
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

And spans

```
<span class="loadNum">Hasha</span>
<span class="loadNum">dbhfb</span>
```

Also can anyone tell how to achieve this that when I press enter on converted input tag it should submit an ajax call.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/114/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-add the `span`, it doesn't have a class.  So the `span.loadNum` selector won't identify it.  [Add the class](http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/115/):

```
$(this).parent().append($('<span />').addClass('loadNum').html($(this).val()));
```

Comment: There is still a bit malfunctioning... spans are changing their places! That doesnt look good!

Comment: @Alexis: I guess you need to modify your logic a bit then.  This addresses the problem you're facing in the original question, but I make no promises that your entire application is correct or ideally implemented.  This answer doesn't introduce the problem you're describing in that comment.

Comment: Okay got it! But there is another problem stated there.. Ajax submitting upon key '13' key

Comment: @Alexis: There is no AJAX in the question.  If you're encountering additional problems in code unrelated to this question you may want to ask a new question.